# find command, enumerate output and allow selection?

Tags: bash, files, find

When I use `find`, it often finds multiple results like

```
find -name pom.xml
./projectA/pom.xml
./projectB/pom.xml
./projectC/pom.xml
```

I often want to select only a specific result, (e.g `edit ./projectB/pom.xml`). Is there a way to enumerate `find` output and select a file to pass into another application? like:

```
find <print line nums?> -name pom.xml
1 ./projectA/pom.xml
2 ./projectB/pom.xml
3 ./projectC/pom.xml

!! | <get 2nd entry> | xargs myEditor
```

?

[Edit] 
I've bumped into some perculiar bugs with some of the solutions mentioned. So I'd like to explain steps to reproduce:

```
git clone http://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git
cd eclipse.platform.swt.git
<now try looking for 'pom.xml' and 'feature.xml' files>
```

**[Edit] Solution 1**
So far a combination of 'nl' (enumirate output), head & tail seems to work if I combine them into functions and use $(!!).

i.e:

```
find -name pom.xml | nl   #look for files, enumirate output.

#I then define a function called "nls"
nls () {
  head -n $1 | tail -n 1
}

# I then type: (suppose I want to select item #2)
<my command> $(!!s 2)

# I press enter, it expands like: (suppose my command is vim)
vim $(find -name pom.xml |nls 2)

# bang, file #2 opens in vim and Bob's your uncle.
```

**[Edit] Solution 2**
Using "select" seems to work quite well as well. e.x:

```
  findexec () {
          # Usage: findexec <cmd> <name/pattern>
          # ex: findexec vim pom.xml
          IFS=$'\n'; 
          select file in $(find -type f -name "$2"); do
                  #$EDITOR "$file"
                  "$1" "$file"
                  break
          done;  
          unset IFS
  }
```

Comment: Is `Your find command | head -TheNumberYouWant` fulfilling your requirements? (With your line: `!! | head -2 | xargs myEditor`)

Comment: Check out [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf), it binds this kind of action to ^T (by default)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `bash`'s built-in `select`:

```
IFS=$'\n'; select file in $(find -type f -name pom.xml); do
  $EDITOR "$file"
  break
done; unset IFS
```

For the "bonus" question added in the comment:

```
declare -a manifest
IFS=$'\n'; select file in $(find -type f -name pom.xml) __QUIT__; do
  if [[ "$file" == "__QUIT__" ]]; then
     break;
  else
     manifest+=("$file")
  fi
done; unset IFS
for file in ${manifest[@]}; do
    $EDITOR "$file"
done
# This for loop can, if $EDITOR == vim, be replaced with 
# $EDITOR -p "${manifest[@]}"
```

Comment: +1 for offering what I suspect is a very little used command verb

Comment: I'm working in it.  `select` doesn't seem to place nicely with altering `IFS`.

Comment: Ah. `( IFS=$'\n'; select file in $(find -maxdepth 2 -name '*.txt'); do echo "$file"; done; )`

Comment: I should have thought of C-style strings.  Well done!

Comment: I'd appreciate some insight, @roaima:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378282/whitespace-safe-procedural-use-of-find-into-select-in-bash

Comment: Wow, epic stuff. Exactly what I wanted. U r uber.

Comment: Edit. I found a case where it breaks down :-|. I edited my post outlining steps to reproduce with the swt git repo. If I try to search for "feature.xml", I get 2 lines that output 3 times. Two items are on the first line and the 3rd item is printed on the 2nd line. Pressing 2/3 selects the 3rd item. So the second item is inacessible.
I can't figure out why, there are no whitespaces in the patch or funny characters..?   
Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/8ZYiMLg.png

Comment: Are you certain?  `select` will use a multi-column layout for its 'menu', so options 1 and 2 being on the same row is normal.

Comment: I must have had low-blood caffeine levels when I was reporting the issue. I re-investigated and it does actually work as expected. Thank you for nice script. (BONUS: would be cool if there'd be a way to be able to select multiple files at once from selection. Like:    findExec pom.xml .... 2 4 12    such that multiple files could be opened at once.

Comment: That can be done by adding a manually injected "quit" option to `select`, removing the `break`, and using a `case` or `if` statement to `break` on the event of choosing the quit option.

Answer (score 3):

Two little functions will help you solve this provided your filenames don't contain newlines or other non-printing characters. (It does handle filenames that contain spaces.)

```
findnum() { find "$@" | sed 's!^\./!!' | nl; }
wantnum() { sed -nr "$1"'{s/^\s+'"$1"'\t//p;q}'; }
```

Example

```
findnum -name pom.xml
     1  projectA/pom.xml
     2  projectB/pom.xml
     3  projectC/pom.xml

!! | wantnum 2
projectB/pom.xml
```

Comment: Handily, the explicit filename `pom.xml` will never contain whitespace (:

Comment: There seems to be some bug in the above.
find -name pom.xml will give me a lot of output, but findnum only gives me a single line.  e.g


./features/org.eclipse.swt.tools.feature/pom.xml
./examples/org.eclipse.swt.examples.ole.win32/pom.xml
./examples/org.eclipse.swt.examples/pom.xml
./examples/org.eclipse.swt.examples.views/pom.xml
./examples/org.eclipse.swt.examples.launcher/pom.xml
./examples/org.eclipse.swt.examples.browser.demos/pom.xml
./local-build/local-build-parent/pom.xml

Comment: @Leo on that same dataset how did you use `findnum`?

Comment: Hopefully this screen shot helps explain the issue: http://i.imgur.com/hfneWJn.png   You may observe that feature.xml yields 3 results. with findnum feature I get an error. with fundnum pom.xml it only prints one result where as find -name pom.xml prints 3 results.  I updated my question to explain how to get dataset. (it's a simple git repo)

Comment: @Leo you're not using it like shown in the example. It's a drop-in replacement for `find`. So where you have `find -name feature.xml` you then use `findnum -name feature.xml`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti, although it could be in a *directory* named with whitespace d:

Answer (score 3):

you could get the head of the total outputs and tail it with -1. this can pipe the output in any other command or editor 
eg.

(get me 100 lines and print me at last pipe the 100)
    find . | head -100 | tail -1

```
xxx@prod01 (/home/xxx/.ssh) $ find .
.
./authorized_keys
./id_rsa
./id_rsa.pub
./id_rsa_b_x.pub
./id_rsa_a_y.pub
./known_hosts

xxx@prod01 (/home/xxx/.ssh) $ find . | head -3
.
./authorized_key
./id_rsa

xxx@prod01 (/home/xxx/.ssh) $ find . | head -3 | tail -1
./id_rsa    



eg: vim "$(find . | head -100 | tail -1)"
```

will get you the 100th line of finding.

Comment: Well, the simple solution seems to be the best. Your answer combined with 'nl' and '$(!!)' seems to work quite well actually. I posted details in my question. Thanks for response.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to edit files after a search, try [sag/sack](https://github.com/sampson-chen/sack).

Example:

```
$ sag skb_copy                                                                
sack__option is: -ag

============> running ag! <============

===> Current Profile: no_profile
===> Using flags: 
===> Searching under: /home/fklassen/git/pvc-appliance/kernel/drivers/ixgbevf
===> Searching parameters: skb_copy


/home/fklassen/git/pvc-appliance/kernel/drivers/ixgbevf/kcompat.c
[1] 195:        skb_copy_bits(skb, offset, buffer, len) < 0)

/home/fklassen/git/pvc-appliance/kernel/drivers/ixgbevf/kcompat.h
[2] 1774:   if (skb_copy_bits(skb, offset, buffer, len) < 0)
[3] 2321:#define skb_copy_to_linear_data(skb, from, len) \
[4] 2323:#define skb_copy_to_linear_data_offset(skb, offset, from, len) \
```

... then to edit the last search result ....

```
F 4
```

Advantage is that you can go back later edit the first search result with

```
F 1
```